# Changing Index of the axis in a Graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a code which will plot a graph of Time VS Amplitude. Now , I want to change the index which is on the horizontal axis. I want to know how I can do it for a single plot and also for the subplots. I want the range of the horizontal axis to be from `0` to `2*pi`.

```
#the following code was written for plotting

fig, (ax1, ax2 ,ax3) = plt.subplots(3 ,constrained_layout = True)                 
fig.suptitle('AMPLITUDE MODULATION' ,color = 'Red')

ax1.plot(message_signal)
ax1.set_title('Message Signal' ,color = 'green')
```

I expect the x-axis to go from `0` to `2*pi` only. In short, I want to customize the indexing of the x-axis

Comment: Does my solution solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah ... It helped me a lot . Thanks

Comment: I am a newbie here , I have no idea how to accept any answer but it helped me

Comment: [See](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) here, there is a greyed out tick mark directly left to my answer, just click it. Thank you

Comment: I have marked it the correct answer ... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xlim` to set the limits of the x-axis for [whole plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html#matplotlib-pyplot-xlim) or [specific axes](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-xlim), e.g. `plt.xlim(0, 1)` or `ax1.set_xlim(0, 1)`.

Here I set the limits for the x-axis to be `[0, 3*pi]`

```
fig, (ax1, ax2 ,ax3) = plt.subplots(3, constrained_layout = True)                 
fig.suptitle('AMPLITUDE MODULATION', color = 'Red')

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
ax1.plot(x, np.sin(x))
ax1.set_title('Message Signal', color = 'green')
ax1.set_xlim(0, 3*np.pi)
```

[image]